# Unitiy Firebase - Update multiple data without deleting other nodes

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am using Firebase in Unity and i am trying to update few values in player node. Player has multiple nodes, but lets say i want to just update name and age. 
 The problem is that updating multiple data based on the documentation is resulting in deleting other player nodes, which were not updated. ( ie when updating only name and age, score will get deleted )

I tried using both SetRawJsonValueAsync and UpdateChildrenAsync and both delete other player nodes. Documentation is saying that UpdateChildrenAsync should specifically not delete other nodes.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data

My question is if i am doing something wrong, since this should work or there is some other way to update only specific nodes without deleting other nodes. I am just looking for simple update like in JS. ( .update({ name: "Jack", age: 20}) )

Code i have

```
PlayerData newServerData = new ServerPlayerData(name, age);
Dictionary<string, object> newServerDataD = newServerData.ToDictionary();
Dictionary<string, object> childUpdates = new Dictionary<string, object>();
childUpdates["User"] = newServerDataD;

FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("")
  .UpdateChildrenAsync(childUpdates)
  .ContinueWithOnMainThread(taskUpdate => {  ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, [reading through the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#basic_write), it looks like `SetRawJsonValueAsync` is expected to overwrite child nodes and delete them:

> Using SetValueAsync() or SetRawJsonValueAsync() in this way overwrites data at the specified location, including any child nodes.

The second half of that quote though is:

> However, you can still update a child without rewriting the entire object. If you want to allow users to update their profiles you could update the username as follows:

```
mDatabaseRef.Child("users").Child(userId).Child("username").SetValueAsync(name);
```

To reproduce this logic in your code, I would do something like this:

```
var root = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.GetReference("User");
var nameTask = root.GetReference("name").SetValueAsync(name);
var ageTask = root.GetReference("age").SetValueAsync(age);
Task.WhenAll(nameTask, ageTask).ContinueWithOnMainThread(taskUpdate=>{ ...
```

Alternatively you can use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#save_data_as_transactions). This will get very pseudo-code-y, so I apologize for that:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.GetReference("User").RunTransaction(mutableData =>{
    // TODO: handle null data in case you hit an empty cache
    mutableData.Child("name").Value = name;
    mutableData.Child("age").Value = age;
    return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
}).ContinueWithOnMainThread(dataSnapshot=> ...
```

I hope that helps! If you would like this as a feature as you expected, you can always file a feature request on the [support site](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) or [on github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues).

--Patrick

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick. The task did the job, i guess its similar to Promise.All() in js? I will be using that for multiple DB updates in the future. Still pity there is no simple way to update DB like in JS, but this is totaly fine. Thanks again.

Comment: You can also use async/await through all this as well, to make it feel like more modern JavaScript :D. The documentation doesn't use it very much since Firebase still supports Unity prior to dotNet4.0 support. Don't be shy about feature requests too, especially where one SDK feels different than another, it's always useful input!